# Want to display two extra elements in each row of table say - 'update' and 'delete' link labels

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

here is my asp code to read a table from database. But while displaying table I want to have extra elements in each row for updation and deletion. How?

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select StudentId, StudentName from tblStudent", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Help me with suggestions.

Comment: show your HTML code please

Comment: Here is an useful reference : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-CRUD-Select-Insert-Edit-Update-Delete-using-Single-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Nothing in HTML. I have idea to read DataSet to HTML table until (DataSet != 0) but how to add those two extra elements.

Comment: in that case just add RowDataBound Event of GridView

Comment: Nothing in HTML? what is Gridview1 then, code behind only? or you are creating the whole Grid dynamically?

Comment: HTML code generates automatically when we create UI right!? I added GridView manually @dirty

Comment: @MohithKovela still show generated code

Comment: when I say HTML, you have to show ASP.net page design code, not code behind, i.e. testpage.aspx ,not testpage.aspx.cs

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try below to show Edit and Delete in addition to Student Id and Name:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True"
                AllowPaging="True" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
                    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
                    OnRowDeleting="GridView1_OnRowDeleting" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_OnSelectedIndexChanged" GridLines="Horizontal">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1px" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1px"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="dgrid" ItemStyle-CssClass="dgrid" />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1px" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1px"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="dgrid" ItemStyle-CssClass="dgrid" />


                           <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentId" HeaderText="Student Id" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="Student Name" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                   </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView>
```